# Capitalise or not foreign demonyms when original language uses lower case and English has no equivalent?

Tags: adjectives, capitalization, proper-nouns, loanwords

In English we capitalise demonyms. Someone from Paris is a Parisian. When we insert words from other languages we indicate the non-English nature of the word with quotation marks or italics. "He had his Italian citizenship recognised *jure sanguinis*," for example. If there is no English-language equivalent of a demonym, and I choose to use one from another language in my English writing, should I capitalise it or not in the case it is not capitalised in the original language?

"We *giardinenses/Giardinenses* (people from Villa Giardino, Córdoba, Argentina) are fighting a battle against disinformation."

Answer (score -1):

If you're using an English word, use English rules. If you're using a foreign word, use rules appropriate to that word.

You've already alluded to that: we say that someone from Paris is a Parisian and that gets a capital letter. However, he would live *la vie parisienne,* and do so in italics to boot.

If a language makes a particular word into a common noun, then when using **that word,** it's a common noun:

> We *giardinenses* are fighting a battle against disinformation.

That would be different if you were coining an English word (in the same way as "Parisian"):

> We Giardinoan men are fighting a battle against disinformation.

This approach is the one advised in *New Fowler's Modern English Usage* (R W Burchfield/OUP, 1998) but the entries on foreign words and French in particular [which it's possible to extend to other languages] are too long to quote directly.

Comment: Obviously, 'If a language makes a particular word into a common noun', it should not be capitalised, but It is not obvious that *giardinenses* in the OP's example is a common noun, rather than a demonym that is not capitalised in the language of its origin (in accordance with the general the rules of that language). The example of *parisenne* is not analogous to *giardinenses*: when somebody uses *parisenne* it is obvious (even apart from the italics) that one is using a foreign word, because there does exist a diferrent English word, *Parisian*.

Comment: If one is coining an English word for the inhabitants of Villa Giardino, why wouldn't that new English word be *Giardinenses*?

Comment: Because that's not the way English forms its words. If you don't like an answer, it's more productive to write your own than argue in comments.